# Gradle: how to clone a git repo in a task?

Tags: git, gradle

Suppose I have a gradle build script and want to write a task to clone a remote git repository. How do I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The cloning can be done using the [Gradle-git plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git). To use the plugin you should download it first:

```
buildscript {
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
  dependencies { classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.2.3' }
}
```

Then write a task like this one:

```
import org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.tasks.*

task cloneGitRepo(type: GitClone) {
        def destination = file("destination_folder")
        uri = "your_git_repo_uri"
        destinationPath = destination
        bare = false
        enabled = !destination.exists() //to clone only once
}
```

Comment: is there any way to clone a specific feature branch of the repo?

Comment: Is this Answer correct still? Seems like since Gradle 2.7 the Git plug-in is no longer needed. Is that correct? https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/386

Comment: how do you specify the branch to clone?

Comment: NOTE: `gradle-git` is dead.  You wanna use `grgit` from http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/grgit-gradle.html, and it includes a way to checkout a specific branch after cloning :)

Answer (score 19):

With newer versions of [gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) (0.7.0 and up), you would create the task like this:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

task clone << {
  Grgit.clone(dir: file('build/repo'), uri: 'git@github.com:user/repo.git')
}
```

Comment: is there any way to clone a specific feature branch of the repo?

Comment: How to use clone operation in custom gradle plugin ?

Comment: @ObaidMaroof, may be to checkout operation using will help [grgit.checkout(branch: 'existing-branch')](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/CheckoutOp.html).

Comment: This is the kind of usage example I’d love to see in the official docs—would have saved me a lot of try-and-error

Comment: unfortunate, page not found anymore. I want to check that solution out, please share if anyone has it.

Answer (score 6):

The aforementioned Gradle-git plugin seems to have moved on from providing straightforward "clone this repo to that directory" functionality, so I wrote a simple task that does just this:

https://github.com/palominolabs/gradle-git-clone-task

Comment: Thank you for that. How would I call that inside another task?

Comment: The task-ish way to do this would be to depend on *another* task that is of type GitCloneTask. However, I don't see any reason why you couldn't create a GitCloneTask object and invoke setUpRepo() if you wanted to! Set properties as desired and fire away: https://github.com/palominolabs/gradle-git-clone-task/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/palominolabs/gradle/task/git/clone/GitCloneTask.groovy

Answer (score 5):

There is a Git plugin - docs here: [Gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git#readme). The plugin has a clone method: [GitClone](http://ajoberstar.org/gradle-git/docs/javadoc/)

Probably something along the lines of:

```
GitClone clone = new GitClone();
clone.setUri("http://remote.repository/");
clone.setDestinationPath("//local/path");
clone.setBare(false);
clone.cloneRepo();
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git/) plugin has a [GitClone task](http://ajoberstar.org/gradle-git/docs/javadoc/index.html?org/ajoberstar/gradle/git/tasks/GitClone.html) that should help. I can't help you on how to use it since I don't know Gradle.

Comment: Yeah, I found it already. You see, I'm a newbie to Gradle, so I need a detailed instruction on how to use the plugin to clone a repo. Gonna upvote your answer anyway, thank you