# Gradle: How to perform git pull through gradle?

Tags: java, git, build, gradle

I want to pull changes from git repo before compilation begins. 
I found this [Gradle: how to clone a git repo in a task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719676/gradle-how-to-clone-a-git-repo-in-a-task), but it clones the repo instead of fetching just the changes.
This could be time consuming if the git server is not on the local network or if the repo is large.

I could not find how to do `git pull` using gradle or the [gradle-git plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create `Exec` task and run any shell/cmd command. No extra plugin dependency required for simple tasks.

```
task gitPull(type: Exec) {
    description 'Pulls git.'
    commandLine "git", "pull"
}
```

Usage: `gradlew gitPull`

You should see smth like this:

```
gradlew gitPull 
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:app:gitPull 
Already up-to-date.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.232 secs
```

Where `Already up-to-date.` is the output from `git pull` command.

Answer (score 7):

The following gradle script should be helpful:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

buildscript {
   repositories { 
      mavenCentral() 
   }
   dependencies { 
      classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.1.0' 
   }
}

task pull << {
   def grgit = Grgit.open(dir: project.file('.'))
   grgit.pull(rebase: false)
}
```

Comment: I went the 'Exec' way as I could not integrate your snippet into my script due to my limited knowledge of gradle. Also, after seeing the exec example I don't see the point of using an external library. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Dojo a plugin can be more efficient (loading and running a plugin is faster than loading and running another executable, particularly on Windows), and it can return values directly (instead of having to encode it, print to stdout, and the caller has to capture and parse the output). Not relevant for simple use cases, but as requirements grow, use cases can become more complicated.