# Gradle-Git plugin usage

Tags: git, gradle

I recently learned of the existence of the [Gradle-Git Plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) for running various Git functionalities from within Gradle. What I need to do is use this to perform git pull, clone, and various file comparison methods.

But as I'm a complete newbie to Gradle (as well as Groovy), I'm a bit lost as to how to get started. I saw some related posts about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719676/gradle-how-to-clone-a-git-repo-in-a-task) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935659/gradle-how-to-perform-git-pull-through-gradle?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I can't seem to get it working; in fact I'm not even sure whether I've installed the plugin correctly in the first place. This is all I've done so far:

- Cloned Gradle-Git onto my desktop
- Imported it into Eclipse as a Gradle project (is this strictly necessary?)
- Tried running build.gradle, which gave 3 instances of the following identical error:

> ```
> startup failed:
> \gradle-git\src\main\groovy\org\ajoberstar\gradle\git\ghpages\GithubPagesPluginExtension.groovy: 34: Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.ghpages.GithubPagesPluginExtension' must be declared abstract or the method 'void credentials(java.lang.Class, org.gradle.api.Action)' must be implemented.
> @ line 34, column 1.
> class GithubPagesPluginExtension implements AuthenticationSupported {
> ^
> ```

If anyone knows what's going on and could help me get this working step by step, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need clone the repo or compile the sources, the binaries are available on the plugin portal (see [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.ajoberstar.grgit))

To apply the plugin (using gradle 2.1+) simply

```
plugins {
    id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "1.6.0"
}
```