# How to checkout and build maven project from gradle?

Tags: gradle

I need to build checkout and build an upstream maven project from my gradle build file:

`mvn clean package -DskipTests -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -P build-distr -Dhbase.hbase.version=1.2.0 -Dhbase.hadoop.version=2.6.0`

Is there a common pattern with gradle for this workflow?  If so, how is this normally done?

Comment: Do you have a maven repository (like a company artifactory) that your maven project is placed on?  Or are you trying to check out directly from an scm system like git?

Comment: I don't have a company maven repository.  my assumption was that I would have to checkout the Apache Zeppelin project from GitHub as part of the build.

Comment: Is it [this version of Zeppelin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/0.6.0)?  If so, it's actually on Maven Central already, the link will show you the appropriate entry.

Comment: If in the future, you should require something that's on a git repo and can't find it on maven central, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719676/gradle-how-to-clone-a-git-repo-in-a-task) will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the provided build only works for Hbase 1.0.  For later versions you need to build Zeppelin from source.  More info here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/interpreter/hbase.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no common way to do this out-of-the-box, but you can reach this with custom tasks:

*Extract maven package*

```
task extractMavenPackage(type: Copy){
  destinationDir file(mvnHomeDir)
  from zipTree(configurations.maven.singleFile)
  includeEmptyDirs = false
  eachFile {  // workaround to skip first-level folder
    List segments = it.relativePath.segments as List
    it.path = segments.tail().join('/')
  }
}
```

*Execute build*

```
task mvnCleanPackage(type: Exec) {
  dependsOn extractMavenPackage, extractZeppelinSources
  commandLine "${mvnHomeDir}/bin/mvn.bat"
  workingDir zeppelinProjectDir
  args "-T", "4"
  // args "-s", "$projectDir/settings.xml" // uncomment it if you want to provide custom settings.xml
  args "clean", "package"
  args "-DskipTests"
  args "-P", "build-distr"
  args "-Phadoop-2.6", "-Dhadoop.version=2.6.0", "-Dhbase.hbase.version=1.2.0", "-Dhbase.hadoop.version=2.6.0"
}
```

See full example on [maven-from-gradle-example](https://github.com/slavashvets/maven-from-gradle-example) github project