# Import repository from github in gradle

Tags: android, git, github, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am building a react native android library which depends on:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
}
```

It turned out that [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) isn't working the way I want so I forked it and I wanted to use my version of this library instead of the official one. I can't find a way to do it though, I searched how to import a library from github inside gradle and I found [ajoberstar/gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) but there is no clear instruction on how to do it and all examples I found doesn't work for me (for example this one: [Gradle: how to clone a git repo in a task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719676/gradle-how-to-clone-a-git-repo-in-a-task)). Is there any easier way on how to accomplish something like that?

EDIT:

This is my structure (simplified):

```
root:
| build.gradle
| settings.gradle
| aars
 | map-util.aar
| libs
 | android
  | build.gradle
```

root build.gradle -> `repositories { flatDir { dirs 'aars' } }`

settings.gradle ->

```
include ":react-native-maps-lib"
project(":react-native-maps-lib").projectDir = file("./lib/android")
```

android/build.grandle -> `compile(name: "map-util", ext:"aar")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is the problem! Let me first make clear though what I wanted to do - I'm building react native project. It uses my forked version of react-native-maps, which uses android-maps-utils. I wanted to fork android-maps-utils and use my forked version.

android-maps-utils produces aar file that I needed to import locally. Following Jeffrey Blattman suggestion I added libs directory inside react-native-maps and put aar file named android-maps-utils.aar there.
I also added this inside react-native-maps build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    flatDir {
      dirs "$rootDir/libs"
    }
  }
}
```

and this inside react-native-maps/android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile(name: "android-maps-utils", ext:"aar")
}
```

Now react-native-maps compiles but my react-native project doesn't due to:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-maps'.
```

So, I also needed to include this line:

```
compile(name: "android-maps-utils", ext:"aar")
```

inside my react native app android directory. Now everything compiles!

Answer (score 1):

Reference the AAR you build from building the forked source somewhere on your local filesystem.

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}
```

then put the artifact in `.../libs`, and add it normally to your dependencies, of course matching the version to what you just built.

Comment: I tried your solution, it doesn't work or I did something wrong (I updated my post)

What is weird project itself builds successfully, but it crashes when used in my react-native project (with error 'Could not find map-util').

Comment: This is exactly my problem: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15854
Could you please recommend me any other way how to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I'd suggest trying it with a plain old Android project to understand if the issue is general or related to react.